# Table Column Animation in Beamer not showing table lines and notes

Tags: tables, beamer, animations

I'm trying to animate a table in beamer. I want to reveal the table column-by-column. I am using \onslide following other examples, but the \midrules and \bottomrules of the table are not appearing until the final slide. If I animate by specifying \onlide for each element of the table instead of for the entire column this is not an issue, but that is much more time consuming to write for larger tables. Is there an easier way to get the table structure lines to appear?

This is my first post (after years of reading others' Q's and A's), so please let me know if I'm messing something up or being unclear. Thank you!

```
\documentclass[10pt, xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}     
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

%The example that I am struggling with
\begin{frame}
\begin{tabular}{>{\onslide<1->}l >{\onslide<1->}c  >{\onslide<2->}c }
\toprule
& Col A & Col B \\
\cmidrule{2-3} 
1 & a & b \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}

%This looks like I want it to, but requires specifying which slide each and every element should appear on.
\begin{frame}
\begin{tabular}{lcc }
\toprule
&\onslide<1->{Col A} & \onslide<2->{Col B} \\
       \cmidrule{2-3} 
\onslide<1->{1} & \onslide<1->{a} & \onslide<2->{b} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here an option which consist of saving column element in a `savebox` then you can apply `\onslide` on this box, you can change the sequence of appearance as you like

```
\documentclass[10pt, xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}     
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newsavebox{\mybox}

\newcolumntype{M}[2]{>{\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}}#1<{\end{lrbox}
  \onslide<#2>{\unhbox\mybox}}}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
\begin{tabular}{M{l}{1-} M{c}{1-} M{c}{2-}}
\toprule
  & Col A & Col B \\
\cmidrule{2-3} 
1 &   a   &   b   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly and makes the syntax even more concise. I appreciate your help.